# Custom Title Bar Causes Exception on Newer Version of Android OS

Tags: android, android-layout

I need help. I've reached that place where I've tried so many things that I either:

A) Have a learning disability.
B) I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

I have an app that has a main activity with no title bar and a bunch of other activities with a custom title bar. On Android 2.3.3, everything works fine. On the latest version of Android (4.2) I get this:

`cannot combine custom titles with other title features`

I'm adding my custom title bar like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(R.string.title_activity_about_us);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
}
```

I'm disabling the title bar on the main screen like this:

```
<style name="MainTableTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I investigated ActionBarSherlock, but that seemed like WAY overkill for what seems so simple. I've also tried various ways of "hiding" the bar based on reading 20+ stackoverflow posts. Bottom line is it seems like it just flat-out doesn't like setting a custom title bar.

All I want to do is have a main activity with NO TITLE BAR and some other activities WITH A TITLE BAR that has some simple things set like background color and text. How do I do this so it works on 2.3.3 and up? I'm fine with nuking everything I have - I just need something that works.

Help...me.....

Comment: What do you consider "child activities" to be, since that term is not normally used in Android development?

Comment: Sorry, I just mean activities AFTER the main one. My main activity has no title bar but when you click on a list item, it opens up a new activity WITH a title bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could figure out the main problem so I ended up creating a custom layout and then just including it in each main layout.

Custom layout (window_title.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:background="#fab41e"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        style="@style/OverlayText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How I included it in each `Activity` layout without having to replicate the XML:

```
<include  layout="@layout/window_title" />
```

This got around the whole runtime exception problem AND I can modify it in each `Activity` as I see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` to `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>` (as you do want a title bar) and ensure that `AppBaseTheme` inherits from `.NoActionBar`-flavored `Holo` theme (e.g., `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`), at least on API Level 11+. So, for example, with your `onCreate()` and this theme, it works:

```
<style name="MainTableTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. When running against 2.3.3, a title bar is displayed on the main activity. Other activities look right.

Against Android 4.2, a simpler-looking title bar is displayed, but it still crashes with the "...cannot combine..." error when trying to load an activity with a custom title bar.

Comment: @Mr.Spock: Since it worked for me here on 4.2, I feel quite confident that what I wrote works on 4.2, with no crashes.

Comment: OK - thanks! You've given me some stuff to look into. Is there some way you could share your entire project (if you have a small one you wrote to help me)? Im not sure of the best way to share it, though. I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but can't put my finger on it yet.

Comment: In a fit of pure rage I decided to just include my title bar custom layout at the top of each activity, using this: <include  layout="@layout/window_title" />. On my main activity I left it off so there wouldn't be a title bar. I can then adjust text, or hide it, how I see fit. Man, wish I had those 10 hours back...